# Sharepoint Rest API Search Query not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

Good Day,

I am currently having calling the Sharepoint Rest API Search Query. I have no idea why it won't work.. Also I am not sure if my URL input is correct, as seen below is the code that I have written up to call the API with jQuery. The query is to get back any files with the name "Before" and it is in the form of XML.

Please do advice on what changes I should make, thank you :)

The URL that I am working with is:

**http://test-sharepoint/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx**

**http://test-sharepoint/Tests/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx**

This is the code I implemented:

```
       function apiCallTest() {

            const adminAccount = 'testUser';
            const adminAccountPassword = 'testPassword';

            const auth = btoa(`${adminAccount}:${adminAccountPassword}`);

            const testQuery = 'BEFORE';

            const apiUrl = "https://test-sharepoint/Test/Documents/Forms/_api/search/query?querytext='BEFORE'"

            const apiUrl2 = "https://test-sharepoint/Test/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx/_api/search/query?querytext=%27BEFORE%27";

            const apiUrl3= "https://test-sharepoint/_api/web/GetListByTitle('SitePages')/Items?$filter=Title eq 'before'"

            const apiUrl4= "https://test-sharepoint/_api/search/query?querytext='BEFORE'"
            
            const headers = {
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${auth}`
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl5,
                headers: headers,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    // Process the search results as needed
                    console.log('Search Results:', data)
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Cannot connect")
                    console.error('Error:', xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        apiCallTest();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you find these API, but there are many errors!

- `apiUrl` is false
- `apiUrl2` is false
- `apiUrl3` is false: replace `web/GetListByTitle('SitePages')` by `web/lists/GetByTitle('SitePages')`
- `apiUrl4` is working!

So, working URLs to search on SharePoint with REST API are:

```
https://test-sharepoint/_api/search/query?querytext=%27BEFORE%27

https://test-sharepoint/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SitePages')/Items?$filter=Title%20eq%20%27BEFORE%27

https://test-sharepoint/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SitePages')/Items?$filter=substringof(%27BEFORE%27,%20Title)
```

Tested on my side on SharePoint 2019.

You can test it on your web browser: open your SharePoint site and change the URL. No need to jQuery to test the query.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply @jleture currently I am having another issue basically the COR policy is blocking my API call.. I have did the necessary settings in the IIS however the problem still persists. 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://testing/Shared%20Documents/query%20result%20BEFORE.xml' from origin 'http:/testing.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Hello, I suggest to create another question as the issue is not the same (and maybe already resolved/documented?). If the request URLs are corrects, please accept this answer. Did you test it in your browser?

Comment: Okay will do so now thank you! I have tested the link in the browser and they work! However they only work on the browser and when fetch the api from my code it runs into the cors policy issue. I will create a new question now